# Angular 2 typescript very slow loading

Tags: typescript, npm, angular

Every little update i'm doing to my angular 2 app using npm (Running my app with the `npm start command`) It takes about ~1-2 minute to reload the files & page..

As you can see in the npm log below, starting **19:50:06**, the process took until **19:51:42** for a single edit. almost 2 minutes.

```
[1] [BS] File changed: app\person-list.component.js
[1] [BS] File changed: app\person-list.component.js
[1] 16.04.17 19:50:06 304 GET /index.html
[1] 16.04.17 19:50:06 200 GET /index.html
[1] 16.04.17 19:50:09 304 GET /css/bootstrap.min.css
[1] 16.04.17 19:50:09 304 GET /app/fonts/font-awesome-4.6.1/css/font-awesome.min.css
[1] 16.04.17 19:50:09 304 GET /node_modules/es6-shim/es6-shim.min.js
[1] 16.04.17 19:50:09 304 GET /node_modules/systemjs/dist/system-polyfills.js
[1] 16.04.17 19:50:09 304 GET /node_modules/angular2/es6/dev/src/testing/shims_for_IE.js
[1] 16.04.17 19:50:09 304 GET /node_modules/angular2/bundles/angular2-polyfills.js
[0] 19:50:10 - File change detected. Starting incremental compilation...
[1] 16.04.17 19:50:12 304 GET /node_modules/systemjs/dist/system.src.js
[1] 16.04.17 19:50:12 304 GET /node_modules/rxjs/bundles/Rx.js
[1] 16.04.17 19:50:12 304 GET /node_modules/angular2/bundles/angular2.dev.js
[1] 16.04.17 19:50:12 304 GET /node_modules/angular2/bundles/http.dev.js
[1] 16.04.17 19:50:12 304 GET /node_modules/angular2/bundles/router.dev.js
[1] 16.04.17 19:50:12 304 GET /node_modules/ng2-bootstrap/bundles/ng2-bootstrap.min.js
[0] 19:50:13 - Compilation complete. Watching for file changes.
[1] 16.04.17 19:50:14 304 GET /node_modules/es6-shim/es6-shim.map
[1] 16.04.17 19:50:14 304 GET /node_modules/systemjs/dist/system-polyfills.js.map
[1] [BS] File changed: app\person-list.component.js
[1] 16.04.17 19:50:14 404 GET /css/bootstrap.min.css.map
[1] 16.04.17 19:50:17 404 GET /node_modules/ng2-bootstrap/bundles/ng2-bootstrap.min.js.map
[1] [BS] File changed: app\LocalStorageEmitter.js
[1] [BS] File changed: app\LocalStorage.js
[1] [BS] File changed: app\person-detail.component.js
[1] [BS] File changed: app\person-list.component.js
[1] [BS] File changed: app\home.component.js
[1] [BS] File changed: app\person.js
[1] [BS] File changed: app\fight.component.js
[1] [BS] File changed: app\main-menu.component.js
[1] [BS] File changed: app\login.component.js
[1] [BS] File changed: app\register.component.js
[1] [BS] File changed: app\member-page.component.js
[1] [BS] File changed: app\sidebar.component.js
[1] [BS] File changed: app\person-menu.component.js
[1] [BS] File changed: app\app.component.js
[1] [BS] File changed: app\boot.js
[1] [BS] File changed: app\main.js
[1] [BS] File changed: app\new-user-hero.component.js
[1] [BS] File changed: app\services\jwt.service.js
[1] [BS] File changed: app\helpers\CustomRequestOptions.js
[1] 16.04.17 19:50:19 200 GET /app/boot.js
[1] [BS] File changed: app\person-list.component.js
[1] 16.04.17 19:50:21 304 GET /node_modules/rxjs/Observable.js
[1] 16.04.17 19:50:22 304 GET /node_modules/rxjs/add/operator/map.js
[1] 16.04.17 19:50:23 304 GET /node_modules/rxjs/Subject.js
[1] 16.04.17 19:50:25 200 GET /app/app.component.js
[1] 16.04.17 19:50:25 200 GET /app/services/jwt.service.js
[1] 16.04.17 19:50:25 200 GET /app/helpers/CustomRequestOptions.js
[1] 16.04.17 19:50:25 304 GET /node_modules/rxjs/observable/PromiseObservable.js
[1] 16.04.17 19:50:25 304 GET /node_modules/rxjs/operator/toPromise.js
[1] 16.04.17 19:50:28 304 GET /node_modules/rxjs/util/root.js
[1] 16.04.17 19:50:28 304 GET /node_modules/rxjs/util/SymbolShim.js
[1] 16.04.17 19:50:28 304 GET /node_modules/rxjs/util/toSubscriber.js
[1] 16.04.17 19:50:28 304 GET /node_modules/rxjs/util/tryCatch.js
[1] 16.04.17 19:50:28 304 GET /node_modules/rxjs/util/errorObject.js
[1] 16.04.17 19:50:44 304 GET /node_modules/rxjs/operator/map.js
[1] 16.04.17 19:50:44 304 GET /node_modules/rxjs/Subscriber.js
[1] 16.04.17 19:50:44 304 GET /node_modules/rxjs/Subscription.js
[1] 16.04.17 19:50:44 304 GET /node_modules/rxjs/subject/SubjectSubscription.js
[1] 16.04.17 19:51:06 304 GET /node_modules/rxjs/symbol/rxSubscriber.js
[1] 16.04.17 19:51:06 304 GET /node_modules/rxjs/util/throwError.js
[1] 16.04.17 19:51:34 304 GET /index.html
[1] 16.04.17 19:51:34 304 GET /node_modules/rxjs/util/ObjectUnsubscribedError.js
[1] 16.04.17 19:51:37 304 GET /node_modules/@angular2-material/sidenav/sidenav.js
[1] 16.04.17 19:51:37 304 GET /node_modules/rxjs/util/isFunction.js
[1] 16.04.17 19:51:37 304 GET /css/bootstrap.min.css
[1] 16.04.17 19:51:37 304 GET /app/fonts/font-awesome-4.6.1/css/font-awesome.min.css
[1] 16.04.17 19:51:37 200 GET /app/boot.js.map
[1] 16.04.17 19:51:37 200 GET /app/app.component.js.map
[1] 16.04.17 19:51:37 200 GET /app/services/jwt.service.js.map
[1] 16.04.17 19:51:37 200 GET /app/helpers/CustomRequestOptions.js.map
[1] 16.04.17 19:51:37 304 GET /node_modules/es6-shim/es6-shim.min.js
[1] 16.04.17 19:51:37 304 GET /node_modules/systemjs/dist/system-polyfills.js
[1] 16.04.17 19:51:37 304 GET /node_modules/angular2/es6/dev/src/testing/shims_for_IE.js
[1] 16.04.17 19:51:38 304 GET /node_modules/angular2/bundles/angular2-polyfills.js
[1] 16.04.17 19:51:38 304 GET /node_modules/systemjs/dist/system.src.js
[1] 16.04.17 19:51:38 304 GET /node_modules/rxjs/bundles/Rx.js
[1] 16.04.17 19:51:38 304 GET /node_modules/angular2/bundles/angular2.dev.js
[1] 16.04.17 19:51:38 304 GET /node_modules/angular2/bundles/http.dev.js
[1] 16.04.17 19:51:38 304 GET /node_modules/angular2/bundles/router.dev.js
[1] 16.04.17 19:51:39 304 GET /node_modules/ng2-bootstrap/bundles/ng2-bootstrap.min.js
[1] 16.04.17 19:51:39 304 GET /node_modules/es6-shim/es6-shim.map
[1] 16.04.17 19:51:39 404 GET /css/bootstrap.min.css.map
[1] 16.04.17 19:51:39 304 GET /node_modules/systemjs/dist/system-polyfills.js.map
[1] 16.04.17 19:51:40 304 GET /app/boot.js
[1] 16.04.17 19:51:40 404 GET /node_modules/ng2-bootstrap/bundles/ng2-bootstrap.min.js.map
[1] 16.04.17 19:51:40 304 GET /node_modules/rxjs/add/operator/map.js
[1] 16.04.17 19:51:40 304 GET /app/app.component.js
[1] 16.04.17 19:51:40 304 GET /app/services/jwt.service.js
[1] 16.04.17 19:51:40 304 GET /app/helpers/CustomRequestOptions.js
[1] 16.04.17 19:51:40 304 GET /node_modules/rxjs/Observable.js
[1] 16.04.17 19:51:41 304 GET /node_modules/rxjs/Subject.js
[1] 16.04.17 19:51:41 304 GET /node_modules/rxjs/observable/PromiseObservable.js
[1] 16.04.17 19:51:41 304 GET /node_modules/rxjs/operator/toPromise.js
[1] 16.04.17 19:51:41 304 GET /app/boot.js.map
[1] 16.04.17 19:51:41 304 GET /node_modules/rxjs/operator/map.js
[1] 16.04.17 19:51:41 200 GET /app/person-list.component.js
[1] 16.04.17 19:51:41 200 GET /app/main-menu.component.js
[1] 16.04.17 19:51:41 200 GET /app/home.component.js
[1] 16.04.17 19:51:41 200 GET /app/fight.component.js
[1] 16.04.17 19:51:41 200 GET /app/login.component.js
[1] 16.04.17 19:51:41 200 GET /app/register.component.js
[1] 16.04.17 19:51:41 200 GET /app/member-page.component.js
[1] 16.04.17 19:51:41 200 GET /app/sidebar.component.js
[1] 16.04.17 19:51:41 200 GET /app/person-menu.component.js
[1] 16.04.17 19:51:41 304 GET /app/app.component.js.map
[1] 16.04.17 19:51:41 200 GET /node_modules/@angular2-material/sidenav/sidenav.js
[1] 16.04.17 19:51:41 304 GET /app/services/jwt.service.js.map
[1] 16.04.17 19:51:41 304 GET /app/helpers/CustomRequestOptions.js.map
[1] 16.04.17 19:51:41 304 GET /node_modules/rxjs/util/root.js
[1] 16.04.17 19:51:41 304 GET /node_modules/rxjs/util/SymbolShim.js
[1] 16.04.17 19:51:41 304 GET /node_modules/rxjs/util/toSubscriber.js
[1] 16.04.17 19:51:41 304 GET /node_modules/rxjs/util/tryCatch.js
[1] 16.04.17 19:51:41 304 GET /node_modules/rxjs/util/errorObject.js
[1] 16.04.17 19:51:41 304 GET /node_modules/rxjs/Subscription.js
[1] 16.04.17 19:51:41 304 GET /node_modules/rxjs/subject/SubjectSubscription.js
[1] 16.04.17 19:51:41 304 GET /node_modules/rxjs/Subscriber.js
[1] 16.04.17 19:51:41 304 GET /node_modules/rxjs/symbol/rxSubscriber.js
[1] 16.04.17 19:51:41 304 GET /node_modules/rxjs/util/throwError.js
[1] 16.04.17 19:51:41 304 GET /node_modules/rxjs/util/ObjectUnsubscribedError.js
[1] 16.04.17 19:51:41 200 GET /app/person-detail.component.js
[1] 16.04.17 19:51:41 200 GET /app/person-list.component.js.map
[1] 16.04.17 19:51:41 200 GET /app/main-menu.component.js.map
[1] 16.04.17 19:51:41 200 GET /app/home.component.js.map
[1] 16.04.17 19:51:41 304 GET /node_modules/moment/moment.js
[1] 16.04.17 19:51:41 200 GET /app/fight.component.js.map
[1] 16.04.17 19:51:41 200 GET /app/login.component.js.map
[1] 16.04.17 19:51:41 200 GET /app/register.component.js.map
[1] 16.04.17 19:51:41 200 GET /app/member-page.component.js.map
[1] 16.04.17 19:51:41 200 GET /app/sidebar.component.js.map
[1] 16.04.17 19:51:41 304 GET /node_modules/@angular2-material/toolbar/toolbar.js
[1] 16.04.17 19:51:41 200 GET /app/person-menu.component.js.map
[1] 16.04.17 19:51:41 304 GET /node_modules/@angular2-material/core/rtl/dir.js
[1] 16.04.17 19:51:41 200 GET /node_modules/rxjs/util/isObject.js
[1] 16.04.17 19:51:41 200 GET /node_modules/rxjs/util/isArray.js
[1] 16.04.17 19:51:41 200 GET /node_modules/rxjs/util/isFunction.js
[1] 16.04.17 19:51:41 200 GET /node_modules/rxjs/Observer.js
[1] 16.04.17 19:51:41 200 GET /app/person-detail.component.js.map
[1] 16.04.17 19:51:41 304 GET /app/template/master.html
[1] 16.04.17 19:51:41 304 GET /node_modules/rxjs/Subject.js.map
[1] 16.04.17 19:51:41 304 GET /node_modules/rxjs/Observable.js.map
[1] 16.04.17 19:51:41 304 GET /node_modules/rxjs/util/root.js.map
[1] 16.04.17 19:51:41 304 GET /node_modules/rxjs/util/SymbolShim.js.map
[1] 16.04.17 19:51:41 304 GET /node_modules/rxjs/util/toSubscriber.js.map
[1] 16.04.17 19:51:41 304 GET /node_modules/rxjs/Subscriber.js.map
[1] 16.04.17 19:51:41 304 GET /node_modules/rxjs/util/isFunction.js.map
[1] 16.04.17 19:51:41 304 GET /node_modules/rxjs/Subscription.js.map
[1] 16.04.17 19:51:41 304 GET /node_modules/rxjs/util/isArray.js.map
[1] 16.04.17 19:51:41 304 GET /node_modules/rxjs/util/isObject.js.map
[1] 16.04.17 19:51:41 304 GET /node_modules/rxjs/util/tryCatch.js.map
[1] 16.04.17 19:51:41 304 GET /node_modules/rxjs/util/errorObject.js.map
[1] 16.04.17 19:51:41 304 GET /node_modules/rxjs/symbol/rxSubscriber.js.map
[1] 16.04.17 19:51:41 304 GET /node_modules/rxjs/Observer.js.map
[1] 16.04.17 19:51:41 304 GET /node_modules/rxjs/subject/SubjectSubscription.js.map
[1] 16.04.17 19:51:41 304 GET /node_modules/rxjs/util/throwError.js.map
[1] 16.04.17 19:51:41 304 GET /node_modules/rxjs/util/ObjectUnsubscribedError.js.map
[1] 16.04.17 19:51:41 304 GET /node_modules/rxjs/observable/PromiseObservable.js.map
[1] 16.04.17 19:51:41 304 GET /node_modules/rxjs/operator/toPromise.js.map
[1] 16.04.17 19:51:41 304 GET /node_modules/rxjs/add/operator/map.js.map
[1] 16.04.17 19:51:41 304 GET /node_modules/rxjs/operator/map.js.map
[1] 16.04.17 19:51:41 304 GET /node_modules/@angular2-material/sidenav/sidenav.js.map
[1] 16.04.17 19:51:41 304 GET /node_modules/@angular2-material/core/rtl/dir.js.map
[1] 16.04.17 19:51:41 304 GET /node_modules/@angular2-material/toolbar/toolbar.js.map
[1] 16.04.17 19:51:41 304 GET /app/template/persons.html
[1] 16.04.17 19:51:41 304 GET /app/template/main-menu.html
[1] 16.04.17 19:51:41 304 GET /app/template/person-menu.html
[1] 16.04.17 19:51:41 304 GET /app/template/sidebar.html
[1] 16.04.17 19:51:42 304 GET /app/template/persons.html
[1] 16.04.17 19:51:42 304 GET /app/template/person-detail.html
```

What could cause it to play so slow after every single file edit?
In the first runs it plays ok, then after about 5 changes it starts loading slow.

Comment: actually from what I see compilation is done in 3 seconds...

Comment: Yeah I see. I changed my question title from slwo compilation to slow file loading

Comment: try it in another browser

Comment: I get why it happens. the proccess is getting out of memory because the compiler is checking for too many file changes at one time. I have no idea why i'm changing one file and it's checking for like 20 file changes.. I'm changing one file and the log writes about 20 lines of text like this: `[1] [BS] File changed: app\home.component.js`.